# Matrix Calculator program in C language. How to avoid redundancy

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to make a program for matrix Calculator and have done this so far. I want to avoid iteration or replication of the statements in my code but I want to restrict using the pointers in this. Can you suggest improvement with the code I can do?

I know I can use structures as well but seems like I see some problem with that. Please help me in suggesting any kind of improvements in this also other feedbacks related to modulation are also acceptable.
Any kind of help will be appreciable. Thanks!

````
#include <stdio.h>

void matrixReadValues(int rows, int columns, int readInput[rows][columns]);
void matrixPrint(int rows, int columns, int readOutput[rows][columns]);
void matrixAddition(int rows, int columns, int matrix1[rows][columns], int matrix2[rows][columns]);
void matrixSubtraction(int rows, int columns, int matrix1[rows][columns], int matrix2[rows][columns]);
void matrixMultiplication(int rowsA, int columnsA, int rowsB, int columnsB, int matrix1[rowsA][columnsA], int matrix2[rowsB][columnsB]);
void matrixTransposePrint(int rows, int columns, int matrixTranspose[rows][columns]);
int matrixDeterminant(int rows, int columns, int matrixDet[rows][columns], int matrixOrder);
void matrixRowEchleonForm(int rows, int columns, int matrix1[rows][columns]);

int main(void){
    
    int operation; //used in swtich statements
    char again = 'Y';
    
    int rowsA, columnsA;
    int rowsB, columnsB;
    int matrixA[rowsA][columnsA];
    int matrixB[rowsB][columnsB];
    
    while (again == 'Y'){


        //this is the operation menu just type A, B, C or D to calculate
        printf("\n \t\t\tOperation Menu\n\n");
        printf("\t1. to Add\n");
        printf("\t2. to Subtract\n");
        printf("\t3. to Multiply two matrices\n");
        printf("\t4. to find the transpose of the matrix\n");
        printf("\t5. to find the determinant of the matrix\n\n");
        printf("\t6. to find the rowecheleon form of the matrix\n\n");
        printf("\tEnter your choice: ");
        scanf(" %d", &operation);
        
        switch (operation){
            
        //Case 1 is for addition of 2 matrices 
        
        case 1:
            printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

            printf("\tEnter the #rows and #cols for matrix B: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsB, &columnsB);

            while ((rowsA != rowsB) && (columnsA != columnsB)){
                printf("\n\tMatrices must be of the same size\n");
                printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

                printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #cols for matrix B: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &rowsB, &columnsB);

            }


            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix A %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsA, columnsA);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix A\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            
            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix B %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsB, columnsB);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsB, columnsB, matrixB);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix B\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsB, columnsB, matrixB);
            
            printf("\t\nAdding the 2 matrices now, we get Matrix A + B:\n\n");
            matrixAddition(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA, matrixB);


            break;
            
            // Case 2 is for subtraction of the 2 matrices
            case 2:
            printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

            printf("\tEnter the #rows and #cols for matrix B: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsB, &columnsB);

            while ((rowsA != rowsB) && (columnsA != columnsB)){
                printf("\n\tMatrices must be of the same size\n");
                printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

                printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #cols for matrix B: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &rowsB, &columnsB);

            }


            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix A %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsA, columnsA);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix A\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            
            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix B %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsB, columnsB);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsB, columnsB, matrixB);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix B\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsB, columnsB, matrixB);
            
            printf("\t\nSubtracting the 2 matrices now, we get Matrix A - Matrix B:\n\n");
            matrixSubtraction(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA, matrixB);


            break;
            
            
        //Case 3 is for addition of 2 matrices 
        
        case 3:
            printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

            printf("\tEnter the #rows and #cols for matrix B: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsB, &columnsB);

            while ((rowsA != rowsB) && (columnsA != columnsB)){
                printf("\n\tMatrices must be of the same size\n");
                printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

                printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #cols for matrix B: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &rowsB, &columnsB);

            }


            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix A %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsA, columnsA);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix A\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            
            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix B %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsB, columnsB);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsB, columnsB, matrixB);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix B\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsB, columnsB, matrixB);
            
            printf("\t\n\tMultiplying the 2 matrices now:\n\n");
            matrixMultiplication(rowsA, columnsA, rowsB, columnsB, matrixA, matrixB);
            
            //Adding the default statemnt if no option matches
            default:
            printf("\nIncorrect option! Please choose a number between 1-4.");
            break;
            
        //Case 4 is for doing the transpose of the matrix
            
        case 4:
            printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsA, columnsA);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            
            printf("\t\nDoing the transpose of the above matrix:\n\n");
            matrixTransposePrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);


            break;
        // Case 5 is for finding the determinant of a matrix    
            case 5:
            printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A. Make sure you add the square matrix: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsA, columnsA);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            
            printf("\t\n Finding the determinant of the above matrix:\n\n");
            
            int detRecievedFromFunction;
            detRecievedFromFunction = matrixDeterminant(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA, rowsA);
            
            printf("%d", detRecievedFromFunction);


            break;
            
            //Writing the Row Echeleon form
            case 6:
            printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix A. Make sure you add the square matrix: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &rowsA, &columnsA);

            printf("\n\tNow Let us enter the elements of Matrix %d x %d matrix.\n\n", rowsA, columnsA);
            
            matrixReadValues(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            printf("\n\t\tMatrix\n\n");
            matrixPrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            
            printf("\t\n Finding the RowElcheleon form of the above matrix:\n\n");
            
            matrixRowEchleonForm(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);
            
            matrixPrint(rowsA, columnsA, matrixA);


            break;
        }
        
            
    }

}

//Function to read the value from the users
void matrixReadValues(int rows, int columns, int readInput[rows][columns]){
    
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++ ){
        for(j=0; j < columns; j++){
            
            printf("\tEnter the elemnts [%d][%d]: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &readInput[i][j]);
                        
        }
    }
    
}

//Printing the matrix values

void matrixPrint(int rows, int columns, int readOutput[rows][columns]){
    
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++ ){
        for(j=0; j < columns; j++){
            
            printf("\t%d\t", readOutput[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
        
}

//Function to add the 2 matrices

void matrixAddition(int rows, int columns, int matrix1[rows][columns], int matrix2[rows][columns]){
    
    int sum[rows][columns];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++ ){
        for(j=0; j < columns; j++){
            
            sum[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
            printf("\t%d\t", sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");               
    }
}

//Function to subtract the 2 matrices

void matrixSubtraction(int rows, int columns, int matrix1[rows][columns], int matrix2[rows][columns]){
    
    int difference[rows][columns];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++ ){
        for(j=0; j < columns; j++){
            
            difference[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] - matrix2[i][j];
            printf("\t%d\t", difference[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");               
    }
}

//Functrion to multiply the 2 matrices

void matrixMultiplication(int rowsA, int columnsA, int rowsB, int columnsB, int matrix1[rowsA][columnsA], int matrix2[rowsB][columnsB]){
    
    int multiply[rowsA][columnsB];
    int i, j, k;
    
    //Initializing all the elemnts of multiply to 0
    for (i = 0; i<rowsA; ++i)
    
        for (j = 0; j<columnsB; ++j)
        {
            multiply[i][j] = 0;
        }
    
    
    // Checking whether the user wants to do "AB" or "BA" multiplication
    
    int options;
    printf("\t What type of operation do you want to perform from A x B or B x A? <Write either 1 for A x B or 2 for B x A>" );
    scanf("%d", &options);
    
    if(options == 1){
        
        // Running the loop for the multiplication of the 2 matrices 
        for (i = 0; i<rowsA; i++){
        
            for (j = 0; j<columnsB; j++){
            
                for (k = 0; k<columnsA; k++){
                
                  multiply[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                }
            printf("\t%d\t", multiply[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
       }
       
    }
    
    
    else if( options == 2){
        
        // Running the loop for the multiplication of the 2 matrices 
        for (i = 0; i<rowsB; i++){
        
            for (j = 0; j<columnsA; j++){
            
                for (k = 0; k<columnsB; k++){
                
                  multiply[i][j] += matrix2[i][k] * matrix1[k][j];
                }
            printf("\t%d\t", multiply[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
       }
    }
       
    
    
    else {
        
        printf("Please add the appropiate values:");
        printf("What type of operation do you want to perform from A x B or B x A? <Write either 1 for A x B or 2 for B x A>" );
        scanf("%d", &options);
    }
    

}

//Printing the transpose matrix values

void matrixTransposePrint(int rows, int columns, int matrixTranspose[rows][columns]){
    
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++ ){
        for(j=0; j < columns; j++){
            
            printf("\t%d\t", matrixTranspose[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
        
}

//Printing the Determinant of Matrix
int matrixDeterminant(int rows, int columns, int matrixDet[rows][columns], int matrixOrder){
    
    int determinant=0, currentColumn, s = 1, i, j, m, n;
    int subMatrixDet[rows][columns];  //This is the matrix which extracted from the enterred matrix (matrixDet[rows][columns]) as a sub matrix
    
    if(matrixOrder == 1){
        
        return(matrixDet[0][0]);
        
    }
    
    else{
        
        // We would be applying the loop to perform the operation for every column
        for(currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < matrixOrder - 1; currentColumn++){
            m = 0, n = 0; //We initialized it because everytime loop will run we will extract new determinant 
            
            //Loop for writing/extracting the sub matrix from the original matrix in order to calculate the minor
            for(i=0; i < matrixOrder; i++){
                for(j=0; j < matrixOrder; j++){
                    
                    subMatrixDet[i][j] = 0;
                    
                    //Since we have to exclude the element which we multiply with the sub determinant matrix
                    if(i !=0 && j !=0 ){
                        subMatrixDet[m][n] = matrixDet[i][j];
                        
                        //Incrementing the Value of n because first the different columns gets filled.
                        if(n < (matrixOrder - 2)){
                            n++;
                        }
                        
                        else{
                            n=0;
                            m++;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }   
            
        }
        determinant = determinant + s*(matrixDet[0][currentColumn] * matrixDeterminant(rows, columns, subMatrixDet, matrixOrder-1) );
        s = -1 * s;
    }
    return determinant;
}

// Converting in the row echleon form
void matrixRowEchleonForm(int rows, int columns, int matrix1[rows][columns]){
    
    int i,j, nextRow;
    int firstElement;
    int firstElementNextRow;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        
        if(matrix1[i][i] != 1){
            
            firstElement = matrix1[i][i];
            
            //Checking if the furst element is the 0
            if(firstElement == 0){
                continue; //We are avoiding to divide the first element by 0
            }
            
            //Now dividing the specific row with different column number by the First element of the row
            for(j=0; j < columns ; j++){
                
                matrix1[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] / firstElement;
                
            }
            
        }
        
        for(nextRow = i + 1; nextRow < rows; nextRow++){
            
            //We are now subtracting the next row with the previous row in order to make the very first elements 0
            firstElementNextRow = matrix1[nextRow][i];
            
            for(j=0; j < columns; j++){
                
                matrix1[nextRow][j] = matrix1[nextRow][j] - (matrix1[i][j] * firstElementNextRow);
            }
        }
        
    }
}

```
````

Comment: This is not working; the addition only adds the second matrix to itself. There is quite a problem with the arrays: matrixA and matrixB are somehow the same zero-sized array.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information. In particular, it's ok to have [variable length arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) since C99, but the array size must be initialized to *some actual value*.

Comment: Well, I just asked for the improvements only. That would be great if you can help in that. Thanks!

Comment: What compiler did you use?

Comment: (@user238196: `There is quite a problem with the arrays` I can see that. I don't see `addition only adds the second matrix to itself` or `matrixA and matrixB are somehow the same […] array`.)

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you will be better off picking a different implementation environment. Or a different project altogether. C and arrays with more than one dimension not fixed at compile time is a misfit.

Answer (score 1):

matrixA and B are the same, as illustrated by this printf:

```
int matrixA[rowsA][columnsA];
int matrixB[rowsB][columnsB];
printf("%p %d %d %p\n", matrixA, rowsA, columnsA, matrixB);
return;
```

Both matrices have the same address:

```
0x7ffd8a489790 0 0 0x7ffd8a489790
```

as a consequence of declaring a `int matrixA[0][0]`.

This leads to wrong results.

---

```
        Enter the elemnts [1][1]: 5

                Matrix A

        5

        Now Let us enter the elements of Matrix B 1 x 1 matrix.

        Enter the elemnts [1][1]: 30

                Matrix B

        30

Adding the 2 matrices now, we get Matrix A + B:

        60
```

**Shouldn't this be 35 ?**

---

The overwriting of A can also be seen by showing it agian after B was entered:

```
    Now Let us enter the elements of Matrix A 2 x 2 matrix.

    Enter the elemnts [1][1]: 1
    Enter the elemnts [1][2]: 2
    Enter the elemnts [2][1]: 3
    Enter the elemnts [2][2]: 4

            Matrix A

    1               2
    3               4

    Now Let us enter the elements of Matrix B 2 x 2 matrix.

    Enter the elemnts [1][1]: 6
    Enter the elemnts [1][2]: 7
    Enter the elemnts [2][1]: 8
    Enter the elemnts [2][2]: 9

            Matrix B

    6               7
    8               9

            Matrix A

    6               7         <------- now A has B's values
    8               9

Adding the 2 matrices now, we get Matrix A + B:

    12              14        <-------- we get B + B
    16              18
```

Comment: but this is working for me. can you explain more please and also help me know how it can be improved?

Comment: Also, I made this code from this but this is just printing the address for me and I don't know why it is so http://pastie.org/p/5Qr5UA9qVYyYuJnVz7Eh8m

Comment: I see, so how can I correct it?

Comment: I just checked again and it is totally working correctly for me. I don't know why it is showing like this in your case.

Comment: @JaskiratSingh Probably a difference in compiler. It has been a while since I've written C, but it looks like your code is invoking undefined behaviour. Highly dangerous situation. In those cases, it will differ between compliers what the exact output is going to be.

Answer (score -1):

`I want to restrict using the pointers in this [matrix calculator code]`
That should prove difficult with C and multidimensional arrays, more below.

The code you present lacks lucid comments.
What comments I find seem to have been written before the (current) code: way to go!
But gotten inconsistent after code changes - `this is the operation menu just type A, B, C or D to calculate` does not comment code that reacts to those characters - or mislead due to an archetypical copy&paste error - `//Case 3 is for addition of 2 matrices` *does* comment a `case 3` (a bit redundantly, at that) which does *not* add (like case 1…), but multiply.
Typos in comments more often than not are just irritating (`//used in swtich`, `default statemnt`, `//Functrion`), but please have a spelling checker help with the UI: `\tEnter the elemnts`, `appropiate` - think of *internationalisation*.

**• code replication**
You are right, there is a conspicuous amount of that.
One of the great powers is giving names, not just to tangible objects, but to abstractions, too.
Seeing

```
prompt("Now let us enter the elements of %d x %d matrix %s", rows, columns, "A");
matrixReadValues(rows, columns, matrix);
matrixPrint(rows, columns, matrix, "A");
```

(or B) for the third time suggests this is a *routine*/*method*/*function* that should be written once and only once.
It needs a name and (in and/or out) parameters like *matrix-values, -name* and *-shape* to be called all over the place.
(It has been observed about 60 years ago that values describing one *object* tend to be used in groups - C does not *support* object orientation.)

Trying to code such in C

```
int getMatrix[][](int m[][], int *rows, int *columns, const char *name) {
        if (null != name && *name)
                printf("\n\tEnter the #rows and #columns for matrix %s: ",
                        name);
        scanf("%d%d", rows, columns);
        return m;
}
```

gives the compiler an opportunity to remind that arrays in C are not like anything else.
While you can get used to one-dimensional arrays, "the problem" with multidimensional arrays is that every dimension but the first must be fixed at compile time. (My attempts to give further advice went down the road to madness and the umpteenth tutorial on how to work around in special cases and general.)

**• code layout**
- alignment of compound statements&blocks is OK
- some `case`es are further to the right than others -
  just like `default:`, veiling the omission of a `break` before
- there is a lot of blank lines separating - nothing, actually, and inconsistently at that.

Whether or not it is a good idea to have considerable application logic in `int main(void)`: it seems too much for one function.
Options include a separate function for each menu option (excepting, conceivably, exit).
Or multiple case statements factoring out common code - how about a first one by *arity*: one or two input matrices, and a second one for dispatch.

The shape logic in prompting for matrix multiplication input is wrong: I don't see the value of offering a choice between *AB* and *BA*, and without a loop, asking for another input if the first one was none of the offered ones is pointless.

**• separation of concerns**
(Most of) Your "arithmetic functions" mix computation and output:
better separate both similar to the handling with `matrixRowEchleonForm()`(sic). (Imaging just a single place where "the" result is put out.)